# Replacing text in WebBrowser VB.Net

Tags: html, vb.net

How do i find and replace some text from some website in WebBrowser with button?

```
<input type="text" value="football"></input>
```

I want to change "football" to "basketball".

I found few codes that MAY work, but i don't know how to use them (such as [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?695171-vb-net-webbrowser-string-replace)).

Comment: If you can't use that code I have trouble understanding how you made the WebBrowser app in the first place? ... Second, you need to post your VB code as well.

Comment: Why would i need to post it? There's nothing important for this question in code. Let me explain you better: Same as WebBrowser1.getElementById("inputfield").InnerText = "basketball". It types in input field basketball. I need code that will find word "football" in tag <input> and change it to "basketball". I hope you understood me :)

Comment: You need to post it because you need to show your efforts, we're not gonna do everything for you. Posting code will also help us understand more precisely what you want. Code is an international language, just like the chemistry's periodic table. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you ask you could loop through all `input` tags and check their `value` attribute. If a match is found just change the attribute to what you want.

[**HtmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx) will return a collection containing all the tags of the specified type found in the document.

```
For Each Tag As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input") 'Iterate through all <input> tags.
    If Tag.GetAttribute("value").ToLower() = "football" Then 'Check if the 'value' attribute is set to 'football'.
        Tag.SetAttribute("value", "basketball") 'Set the attribute to 'basketball' instead.
        Exit For 'Exit the loop.
    End If
Next
```

Remove the `Exit For` line if you want to replace `football` with `basketball` for ***all*** input tags in the document.

Also note that I used `ToLower()` to make the string lowercase, thus providing case-insensitive string comparison.

Comment: This works! Thank you VERY much, you saved my life! <3